# How to allow user to add to, but not edit, a post?

Tags: custom-field, front-end

I saw something very nifty on peerwise (basically a med students social network for making exam questions) that allows people to make additions to something but not edit the original post.

I appreciate that isn't wordpress but was thinking I could do something similar with my p2 wordpress install.

Basically add an unlimited number of (or e.g. 5) extra fields that are blank when writing the original post but can be 'edited' to add more content to a post.

Does this seem like a plausible solution to allow users to add to but not edit a post? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Why not just use comments?

Comment: because of the environment I'll be using, the posts tend to hold information that's relevant to everyone with long discussions underneath - important stuff needs to stay at the top. I don't think comments are practical for the purpose unfortunately. Thanks though!

Comment: to give a bit more background I'm using p2 here for a team environment. User A might write a post with a document. User B should be able to suggest and amendment to the document without being able to edit the original post.

Comment: You might try searching the site for ["collaborative"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=collaborative) and similar keywords and see if you can get a start.

Comment: Why not modify the comments form to have 2 submit buttons - 'Post as Comment' and 'Post as Amendment'. There are several action hooks in comment-template.php that you can use to do this. There are also hooks in wp-comments-post.php that you can use to do the post processing. I had a cursory look and it looks doable but not trivial.

Comment: @MagentaCuda are you serious! that's an amazing plan. any idea at all how I could go about this?

Comment: also a problem that I see with this is you can't upload to comments (especially not in p2)

Comment: What is p2? By upload do you mean attachments, such as images?

Comment: p2 is a [wordpress theme by automatic](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/p2). And yes I meant attachments (but rather than just images I mean files like word documents and pdfs - I've enabled these mime types in wordpress).

Comment: If you also want to do attachments then using the comments form will not work. I think you will need some sort of editor widget.

Comment: so back to the original plan - perhaps some sort of repeater field is the solution?